# VSCode & Java Build Issues

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I'm a Java noob, inheriting a beastly legacy Java project.  I'm trying to get this project working with VS Code.  I am able to run the Gradle build tasks and build successfully.  However, when VS Code launches the workspace it is getting build failures, which also causes issues debugging.

How can I get the default VS Code build mechanism to use a Gradle build task in place of whatever it's doing?  Or, can someone tell me what VS Code (Java) uses as a default build mechanism?  For reference, I do have the Java Extension Pack and Gradle Tasks / Gradle Language Support extensions.

Comment: Can you post the error screenshot?  Also, there's a command **Tasks: Configure Default Build Task**, but there's no gradle in its option, you can [custom tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Molly!  There were actually gradle options in this command for me, maybe from the gradle extensions & gradle scripts in my project.  I'll give that a try.  Regarding the error I'm getting, it's a compile error that doesn't happen in the gradle build because the gradle build excludes some classes.  So the specific error wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: For reference, I believe this Default Build Task command helps with overriding the build command that is used with (Ctrl+Shift+B).  When I set this task, it did the Gradle build with this shortcut, but the workspace refresh still was using some other build mechanism with the Java Language Server.

Comment: Refreshing workspace uses the command **clean java language server workspace**.